# How to make a parabola-like shape + color overlay in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

So I am trying to produce a figure similar to this to this

[image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

- How can I make the parabola-like shape (blue one)?
- How can I make color overlay?

  ```
      \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
      \begin{document}
      \tikzset{>=latex}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \shade[top color=orange!30!white,bottom color=orange!30!white] 
      (0,0.5) parabola (0.9,2.7) |- (0,2.7);
      \shade[top color=orange!30!white,bottom color=orange!30!white] 
      (0,0.5) parabola (-0.9,2.7) |- (0,2.7);

      \draw[->=stealth, thick] (0,0)--(2.5,0) node[right]            {$g_\uparrow\left(E\right)$};
      \draw[->=stealth, thick] (0,0)--(-2.5,0) node[left]            {$g_\downarrow\left(E\right)$};
      \draw[->=stealth, thick] (0,-2)--(0,4) node[above]{$E$};

      \draw (0,0.5) parabola (1,3.2);
      \draw (1.7,2.7) -- (0,2.7);   
      \draw (0,0.5) parabola (-1,3.2);
      \draw (-1.7,2.7) -- (0,2.7);
      \node[] at (2.1,2.7) {$E_F$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
  ```

Comment: For the overlay bit, just `\fill` the path normally with `opacity=<value>` or `fill opacity=<value>` for some value greater than zero and less than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following result of my attempt to solve your problem :-)

[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\fill[red!30!white]
        (-0.9,2.7) parabola bend (0,0.5) (0.9,2.7) -- cycle;
\draw   (-1.0,3.2) parabola bend (0,0.5) (1.0,3.2);
%
\draw[<->,thick] 
        (-2.5,0) node[left]  {$g_\uparrow\left(E\right)$} --
        ( 2.5,0) node[right] {$g_\downarrow\left(E\right)$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-2)--(0,4) node[above]{$E$};
\draw   (-1.7,2.7) -- (1.7,2.7)  node[right] {$E_F$};
%
\draw[fill=blue!50,semitransparent,rotate=90, xshift=17mm]
        (-0.8,0) parabola bend (0,-1) (0.8,0) -- cycle;
\clip (0,2.7) rectangle +(-1,-1.6);
\draw[fill=blue!50,semitransparent,rotate=90, xshift=25mm]
        (-0.8,0) parabola bend (0,1) (0.8,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```